# Find Data in Sheet and fill textboxes in User Form

Tags: vba, userform

I stuck in following Prob.
What do I have ?
I Have a UserForm (UF) and 9 Textboxes

```
1Prename
2Name
3KST
4Code
5PhoneNr
6MailAdress
etc
9Ware
```

I Have in the same Workbook a Sheet named "DATA"

```
Column E named Ware
Column J named PreName
Column K named Name
Column L until P the rest of the mentioned Values
```

The Data Sheet is not static. Means It grows by record a new entry (new Customer)

What should the code do?
What will I do?
In a first Step

By Entering the Prename  and Name in the Textboxes it should check the Sheet "DATA" if the Pre,-Nname and the rest of the Information belonging to the Prename , Name already exist.

If it exists, if there is a match.. a Msgbx should appear with all found Prenames, Names, etc

For Exmpl Peter Mayer; Peter Maier; Peter Meier ... Code, Mailadress, MailCC, Phone, KST
  Msgbx "Prename (Peter), Name (Mayer,Maier,Meier); Code, MailAdress, MaiCC, Phone, KST"; vbCHoose a Customer and submit all Informations to UserForm; Vb Not Found New Entry in User Form means.. back to User Form

In a 2nd Step:

If there was a match  and the Textboxes are filled with the found Adress and other Data from the sheet UF.Ware.Value should be checked if the Costumer ordered a new Item or the Same Item again.

Means:by typing in the Item in UF.Ware.Value check Sheets("Data") Column E.
If its matching Submit to User Form if it does not matcvh then also submit to Textbox Ware in User Form.

What have I done?

I wanted to create Step 1 but as a newbe on VBA I stuck

Heres my Code

```
Dim Vorname As String
Dim FName As String
Dim OrgCode As String
Dim TeleNr As Byte
Dim MailArdess As Integer
Dim cNum As Integer


cNum = 9


Set Reg1 = UserForm1.Vorname
Set Reg2 = UserForm1.FName
Set Reg3 = UserForm1.KST
Set Reg4 = UserForm1.OrgaCode
Set Reg5 = UserForm1.TeleNr
Set Reg6 = UserForm1.MailAdress

'Check to see if value exists
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("DATA").Range("J:P"), Me.Vorname.Value) = 0 Then
MsgBox "Name nicht korrekt"
Me.Vorname.Value = ""
Exit Sub
End If

With Me
Vorname = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(UserForm1.Vorname.Value(Me.Vorname), Sheets("DATA").Range("Lookup"), 11, 0)
'.Reg3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(KST(Me.Vorname), Sheets("DATA").Range("Lookup"), 16, 0)
'.Reg4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(OrgaCode(Me.Vorname), Sheets("DATA").Range("Lookup"), 12, 0)
'.Reg5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(TeleNr(Me.Vorname), Sheets("DATA").Range("Lookup"), 15, 0)
'.Reg6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MailAdress(Me.Vorname), Sheets("DATA").Range("Lookup"), 16, 0)
End With
End Sub
```

Hoping you have abetter idea
Thx Peter

Comment: Besides the code writing, are you sure that having everything summarized in a message box will be helpful? What if the found data is to big for it to be shown like that?

Answer (score 0):

For the first request (get the users information) I propose you the following:

- First use subcodes & call them from your userform. You can save them in the userform, but its usually a better way to develop these codes, as you won't need to repeat the code if you need it again. I'm using the following Sub to test the code I created.

```
Sub Test_PetesPrj()

Dim Var_Test As String

Var_Test = "Peter"
Call PetersProjekt(Var_Test)

End Sub
```

Then, to make it faster, I recommend you to create a name for the range you will be using:

[image: Named range using offset function]

It's formula is:

```
=OFFSET(DATA!$J$1, 0, 0, COUNTA(DATA!$J:$J), 1)
```

Then, the code per se:

```
Sub PetersProjekt(Vorname As String)

Dim String_Print As String
Dim WSh As Worksheet, Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range, Rng4 As Range
Dim xRng2 As Long

cNum = 9

'Flip: You don't need "Set" if you store strings or numbers, only when storing objects

Set WSh = Sheets("DATA")
'I'm reducing your range to a single column, to make data extraction easier (offsetting)
Set Rng1 = WSh.Range("Offset_Column")

'Check to see if value exists
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng1, Vorname) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Name nicht korrekt"
        Exit Sub
    End If

'Listing found entries
    'Initial Text
    String_Print = "Ich habe die folgenden Personen gefunden:" & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
    'I recommend using a filter to avoid looping through too much data.
    Rng1.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Vorname
    Set Rng1 = Rng1.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng1.Rows.Count - 1, Rng1.Columns.Count)
    Set Rng2 = Rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each Rng3 In Rng2
        Var_Name = Rng3.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Var_Kode = Rng3.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Var_Addr = Rng3.Offset(0, 3).Value
        String_Print = String_Print & " - " & Vorname & " - " & Var_Name & " - " & Var_Kode & " - " & Var_Addr & Chr(10)
    Next Rng3

    MsgBox String_Print

    WSh.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

Which will give the following result:

[image: Message Box]

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

For the second part, I don't really understand it...

Comment: is there any possibility to upload my file?

Comment: Hi Felipe thx for Your Help! I appreciate that!  Question.. What if the Sheet "DATA" is  dynamic?  Is it possible to create a message box that allows me to make a choice of an entry and if so.. is it possible to fill my textboxes in the User Form with the choosen Entry?

Comment: Hi Pete, for the Dynamic spreadsheet, that's actually why we are using "=OFFSET(DATA!$J$1, 0, 0, COUNTA(DATA!$J:$J), 1)", to allow it to. The OFFSET function will create a range from your entry point ($J$1) to the count of the column: if you add a new row, you'll change that count which in turn will expand your range automatically. Check this out: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html

Comment: A message box will not help to select, only to show results. You will need to use a userform. I would recomend you to fill in a Combobox that automatically searches for your results & then add a button that goes & look to the selected entry for further processing.

Comment: So you will have a userform for main information that in turn calls another userform for users' search. With the confirmation of the second userform you can fill in the first. But it's not a msgbox (msgboxes are only to show confirmations).